# Can I get the byte representation of an R float?

Tags: r, floating-point

I'm trying to read in a complicated data file that has floating point values. Some C code has been supplied that handles this format (Met Office PP file) and it does a lot of bit twiddling and swapping. And it doesn't work. It gets a lot right, like the size of the data, but the numerical values in the returned matrix are nonsensical, have NaNs and values like 1e38 and -1e38 liberally sprinkled.

However, I have a binary exe ("convsh") that can convert these to netCDF, and the netCDFs look fine - nice swirly maps of wind speed.

What I'm thinking is that the bytes of the PP file are being read in in the wrong order. If I could compare the bytes of the floats returned correctly in the netCDF data with the bytes in the floats returned wrongly from the C code, then I might figure out the correct swappage.

So is there a plain R function to dump the four (or eight?) bytes of a floating point number? Something like:

```
> as.bytes(pi)
[1] 23 54 163 73 99 00 12 45 # made up values
```

searches for "bytes" and "float" and "binary" haven't helped.

Its trivial in C, I could probably have written it in the time it took me to write this...

Comment: And as a conclusion, turns out the data is actually encoded in some wacky custom compression scheme and not straight 8 bytes in any order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**rdyncall** might give you what you're looking for:

```
library(rdyncall)
as.floatraw(pi)
# [1] db 0f 49 40
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "floatraw"
```

Or maybe `writeBin(pi, raw(8))`?

Comment: `writeBin` is the solution. `as.floatraw` converts to a 4-byte single-precision.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that *must* exist in the serialization code because R merrily sends stuff across the wire, taking care of endianness too.  Did you look at eg Rserve using it, or how digest passes the char representation to chosen hash functions?

After a quick glance at `digest.R`:

```
R> serialize(pi, connection=NULL, ascii=TRUE)
 [1] 41 0a 32 0a 31 33 34 39 31 34 0a 31 33 31 38 34 30 0a
[19] 31 34 0a 31 0a 33 2e 31 34 31 35 39 32 36 35 33 35 38
[37] 39 37 39 33 0a
```

and

```
R> serialize(pi, connection=NULL, ascii=FALSE)
 [1] 58 0a 00 00 00 02 00 02 0f 02 00 02 03 00 00 00 00 0e
[19] 00 00 00 01 40 09 21 fb 54 44 2d 18
R>
```

That might get you going.

Come to think about it, this includes header meta-data.

Comment: what kind of text connection does `writeBin` take?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: I did just test that and it does indeed fail, so I will remove the reference to writeBin (and you shoot quickly with the downvote).  But methinks there should still be an R base solution...

Comment: if you serialize `rep(10,pi)` you see the repeating pattern is 40 09 21 fb 54 44 2d 18, so its encoding pi into 8 bytes. If I `save` pi to a file (with `compress=FALSE`) I see 0940 fb21 4454 182d when I dump the file - same numbers, different order. So I think if I chop the first 22 bytes I should get somewhere, although my data file says its Float32, which should only be four bytes...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel `writeBin(pi, raw(8))` does something, not sure if it's right at first glance.

Comment: @Spacedman but R internally only has `numeric` aka `double` aka eight bytes. For conversion to four you may need a different package such as ff or rdyncall.

Comment: But second arg to `writeBin` has to be a connection, will `raw(8)` be one?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel from `?writeBin`, `con` can be "A connection object or a character string naming a file or a raw vector".

Comment: ?writeBin says " If ‘writeBin’ is called with ‘con’ a raw vector, it is just an indication that a raw vector should be returned." So I think writeBin is my answer. Anyone want to put that in an answer?

Comment: I had but @MatthewPlourde made me take it out :)  More seriously, the quick tests I did lead to 'NA introduced by coercion' which does not sound right...

Answer (score 0):

The package **mcga** (machine-coded genetic algorithms) includes some functions for bytes-to-double and doubles-to-byte conversions. For handling the bytes of pi, you can use DoubleToBytes like:

```
> DoubleToBytes(pi)
```

[1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcga/index.html)  24  45  68  84 251  33   9  64

For converting bytes to double again, BytesToDouble() can be used instead:

```
> BytesToDouble(c(24,45,68,84,251,33,9,64))
```

[1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcga/index.html) 3.141593

Links:

[CRAN page of mcga](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcga/index.html)

Comment: look also ByteVectorToDoubles() and DoubleVectorToBytes() for vectorized version of these functions.